# I want to show the items of a collection in a table, the collection is given in the dropdown, once selected, the items should be visible on table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have 3 different collections in my firebase firestore
namely "A", "B" and "C"
the collections have a number of data in them

the collection names are given in dropdown options
if "A" is being selected, the data allocated to "A" should be visible in a table

i tried different ways, but the page shows data only for one collection and if the dropdown is changed to a different value, the table does not get updated

here is a code: -

```
    useEffect(() => {
      const unsub = onSnapshot(
        collection(db, 'Teachers/year/' + course),
        (snapShot) => {
          let list = [];
          snapShot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            list.push({
              id: doc.id,
              ...doc.data()
            });
          });
          setData(list);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );

      return () => {
        unsub();
      };
    }, [])
```

Comment: Are you using any libraries for `dropdown`s and `table`s, if so please mention. Also please try adding some code examples to your question. That way it will be easier to help you.

Comment: i am not using any dropdown libraries nor the table